# entity framework column projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this model:

```
public partial class SystemUser
{
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Pass")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Admin")]
    public Nullable<bool> Type { get; set; }

}
```

this function return all record of SystemUser:

```
    public IEnumerable<object> GetAll()
    {
        var Users = Ctx.SystemUsers.ToList().Select(u => new SystemUser
        {
            Username = u.Username,
            Type = u.Type
        });

        return Users.ToList();
    }
```

but this query also have password column
I dont need this.how can i remove this column from query?
i dont want use anonymus type because it remove dataannotation

Comment: Remove the first `ToList()` and you'll be fine

Comment: Why return `IEnumerable<object>` when you know you're returning `IEnumerable<SystemUser>`?

Comment: @haim770 exception occured

Comment: datagrid work with a lot of objects cause of this we must return IEnumerable<object>

Comment: Does the presence of the `Password` column in the database interaction really make a *noticeable* difference in the performance of this application?  It sounds like you might be trying to micro-optimize.  Or is there some security reason why the `Password` column shouldn't be included in this back-end-only interaction?

Comment: @David for security reasons it shouldn't shown to user

Comment: @Mohammad: It's not being shown to the user.  (In fact, nothing in the posted code is showing anything to a user.)  This function isn't returning that value, so there's no way for any user to see that value.  (Unless users are sniffing the traffic between your application and your database.  In which case you have *much* bigger problems.)

Comment: @David yes u right.but i dont want display column of password.its unneccesery to shown

Comment: @Mohammad: Then don't display it.  That's a UI concern, unrelated to the code shown.

Comment: @David i use wpf and mvvm pattern
many diffrent entity connected to datagrid and always in change and columns are very diffrent it is not possiple to control column in ui

Comment: @Mohammad: In MVVM wouldn't you have a second ViewModel to translate between this model and the view?  That's how you control the UI.  If your ViewModel doesn't have a `Password` field then the UI won't bind to that field.  Don't bind your views directly to your database, that's not MVVM.

Comment: @David i got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return [`Anonymous Types`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)  in `GetAll()` method. Change `GetAll` like this:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetAll()
{
    var Users = Ctx.SystemUsers.ToList().Select(u => new
    {
        User = u.Username,
        Admin = u.Type
    });

    return Users.ToList();
}
```

Comment: your answer was good but i want use space word for example 
[Word1 Word2]  = u.Username
how i fix it?

Comment: @Mohammad you can't, C# keywords can't have a space in them

Answer (score 0):

No way of doing this without raw sql. You always fetch entire table row with Entity Framework.

Comment: Not always, if we use anonymous type for select and commit the query after the select `Ctx.SystemUsers.Select(u => new
    {
        User = u.Username,
        Admin = u.Type
    }).ToList();`, just the required properties will be fetched

Comment: @TaherRahgooy yes you right but I Want use Space  word
نام کاربری = u.Username
have an idea?

Comment: @TaherRahgooy as far as I know, EF doesn't support projecting to anonymous types (just to named ones), that'll probably throw an exception

Comment: @Jcl, It's easy, just test it with simple example. The opposite is true, the named one will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetAll()
{
    return Ctx.SystemUsers.Select(u => new 
    {
        Username = u.Username,
        Type = u.Type
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This throws a run-time error, linq-to-entities does not supports non-anonymous types to construct the `Select`.

Comment: the error is : "The entity or complex type 'SystemUser' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Column "Password" don't remove. You can use interface for two classes inheritance this interface with two column. But, in DbSet you will use full class

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DTO and [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) to support this scenario:-

```
public class SystemUserDto
{
  [Display(Name = "User")]
  public string Username { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Admin")]
  public Nullable<bool> Type { get; set; }
}

...

Mapper.CreateMap<SystemUser, SystemUserDto>();

...

public IEnumerable<SystemUserDto> GetAll()
{
    var Users = Ctx.SystemUsers.Project().To<SystemUserDto>();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have many entities in my app that have this situation
according to your answer I must create many DTO Class 
is it an good idea?

Comment: @Mohammad yes, if you need them

Answer (score 0):

Based on an unnecessarily involved exchange of comments across more than one question, it sounds like what you're *really* asking is:

> I have a type which includes a `Password` field, which I get from the database with Entity Framework.  This type includes data annotations which I need to use in an auto-generated UI.  I have no control over the UI.  How can I provide the UI with a type which includes these data annotations, but doesn't include the `Password` field?

In that case, define another type:

```
public class SystemUserViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Admin")]
    public Nullable<bool> Type { get; set; }
}
```

And transform to that type:

```
Ctx.SystemUsers.ToList().Select(u => new SystemUserViewModel
{
    Username = u.Username,
    Type = u.Type
});
```

If you use an anonymous object, you don't have a class definition so you don't have any attributes (data annotations).  If you use your `SystemUser` type then you have a `Password` property.  To use something which is neither of these things, you have to define a type.